# Error when deserializing

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to write some code to deserialize an XML file. I've looked around a bit and found something which has led me to the following method:

```
    public static void Deserialize(string filePath)
    {
        RootObject ro = null;
        string path = filePath;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        ro = (RootObject) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }
```

But all I get is this error and I'm not sure what's causing it:

There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

The RootObject you see in Deserialize() is this one: I'm new to XMl serializing/deserializing so I'm not sure if I've defined it 100% correctly.

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public Services Services { get; set; }
    }

    public class Services
    {
        public Service TileMapService { get; set; }
    }

    public class Service
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using this method to create the XML files in the first place and it seems to work fine:

```
    public static void WriteToXmlFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite) where T : new()
    {
        TextWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
            writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (writer != null)
            {
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

It gets me an XML file that looks like this:

```
<RootObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Services>
    <TileMapService>
      <Title>Some title</Title>
      <href>http://something</href>
    </TileMapService>
  </Services>
</RootObject>
```

Comment: How do you use the method "WriteToXmlFile" and "Deserialize"? I've tried you code and works fine.

Comment: There is often an inner exception which tells you more detail about what went wrong.

Comment: btw; that `try`/`finally` should just be a `using`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. The "There is an error in XML document (2, 2)." might be because your *actual* file (not the one created by `WriteToXmlFile<T>`) has whitespace at the start, or is using the wrong namespace. Check the `.InnerException` for more detail, or (perhaps simpler) please post the *actual* xml file contents. Example of it working fine (along with some recommended tweaks to the two key methods):

```
static void Main()
{
    RootObject obj = new RootObject
    {
        Services = new Services
        {
            TileMapService = new Service
            {
                Title = "abc",
                href = "def"
            }
        }
    };
    WriteToXmlFile("foo.xml", obj);
    var loaded = Deserialize<RootObject>("foo.xml");
    var svc = loaded.Services.TileMapService;
    System.Console.WriteLine(svc.Title); // abc
    System.Console.WriteLine(svc.href); // def
}
public static void WriteToXmlFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite)
{       
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
    }
}
public static T Deserialize<T>(string filePath)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also found out that it works fine. I was just calling the method the wrong place which somehow caused the error. Your tweaks also makes a lot of sense. Thanks for that.